# NavigationLink SwiftUI causes problem in loading images

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am building an app following somewhat this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xetrbmnszjc. I decided to include API calls in it to fetch images from flickr. I have a problem, when I use an Image for Navigating to the details view, the image is not seen. If I remove the `NavigationLink`, it works fine.

[image]

[image]

The functionality of `NavigationLink` works fine though in the case when the images are not shown.

This is the code for calling view.

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(self.category.uppercased())
                    .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
                            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                                ForEach(self.items, id: \.id){
                                    item in
                                    
                                    NavigationLink(destination: imageDetail(item:item)){
                                        imageItem(item:item)
                                            .frame(width:300)
                                            .padding(.trailing,30)
                                        }
                                }
                            }.onAppear{
                                Api().getPosts(url:"https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=\(self.category)&format=json&nojsoncallback=1",completion: {
                                    (posts) in self.items = posts
                                })
                            }
                        }
            }.padding(.leading, 20)
```

This is the relevant code for `imageItem`

```
 var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: item.media.m.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: ""))!, placeholder: Text("Loading..")
            )
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width:300,height: 300)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .shadow(radius: 10)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5){
                Text(item.title)
                    .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                Text(item.description)
                    .font(.system(size: 20, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(.primary) .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .lineLimit(2)
                    .frame(height: 40)
            }
        }
        
    }
```

`AsyncImage` is the class copied from https://www.vadimbulavin.com/asynchronous-swiftui-image-loading-from-url-with-combine-and-swift/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default NavigationLink renders Image in template mode, so you just need to provide correct mode explicitly, like

```
AsyncImage(url: URL(string: item.media.m.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: ""))!, placeholder: Text("Loading..")
)
.renderingMode(.original)
```